# convert matrix output to R code

Tags: r

Suppose I found a several matrices like this in a paper or tutorial without the R code that generate such matrices. Suppose I would like to regenerate (or even use them in different function) these matrices using R. So, Is there a simple way that I convert the output of matrix into R code. That is if I have the following matrix, how I can convert it to R code.

```
> Matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    5    0    0    0    0
[2,]    2    2    0    0    0
[3,]    3    3    3    0    0
[4,]    1    4    4    4    0
[5,]    4    1    1    1    1
```

Comment: Did you meant `dput(Matrix)`

Comment: No I mean covert matrix output from tutorial to a matrix object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your goal is, but if you want to copy/paste a matrix output (e.g. from a tutorial) and convert it to a matrix object you could do something like

```
mat_string <- "     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    5    0    0    0    0
[2,]    2    2    0    0    0
[3,]    3    3    3    0    0
[4,]    1    4    4    4    0
[5,]    4    1    1    1    1"

mat_list <- strsplit(strsplit(string,"\n")[[1]][-1],"    ")
mat <- do.call("rbind",mat_list)[,-1]
class(mat) <- "numeric"

mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    5    0    0    0    0
[2,]    2    2    0    0    0
[3,]    3    3    3    0    0
[4,]    1    4    4    4    0
[5,]    4    1    1    1    1
```

Comment: exactly what I want. Could you please explain why do you use `")[[1]][-1],"    ")`

Comment: `strsplit()` returns a list of length one, I index this first (and only) element using `[[1]]`. I don't need the first row of the matrix (the column names), I therefore remove it with the `[-1]`.